# how to post on 'visitor post' using facebook javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to create a post that will appear on the recipients 'Visitors Post'. As a test, I am trying to target this page: https://www.facebook.com/SenatorMikulski/. I went to this site http://findmyfbid.com/ to get the user id, which is 142890125771427. Then I am doing this in my code;

```
  ezfb.api('/me/feed','post',{message:'We will miss you',to:[142890125771427]}, function (res) {

     debugger
    });
```

The post succeeds but it appears on my timeline and not on the Senator's Visitor Post. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out my mistake. The end point should be 142890125771427/feed